# Numeric textbox with regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

im trying to do a numeric textbox in asp.net using regex, and came up with:

```
^[^\s]+[/d]+[^\s]$
```

I want it to disallow leading/trailing whitespace, and allow only numbers.

Any clue why it doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to disallow whitespace and other characters, why don't you try ^\d+$ and inverse the way of evaluation in your code?

Comment: That forward-slash in the OP's regex should have been a backslash, and the square brackets are redundant.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this `^\d+$`. `\d` matches digits. The one you wrote does not work because you are using `/d` instead of `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex currently means "anything but whitespace, followed by slashes and d-letters, followed by one more of anything but whitespace". A simple `^\d+$` is sufficient.